# Merging a split file inside a Windows docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, windows-container

I am new to `Docker` so trying to figure something out.

At an absolute basic, I am trying to add some split files in a `docker container`, add and install `7-zip`, and `merge` these split files inside. I managed to do all but the last, which are present in an image / container.

For the last part, I need a separate image / dockerfile, so if I choose, I can decide which split packet to build, so I derive from the first image (containing split files, and installed 7zip) and use CMD to pass arguments listing out which files it needs to merge into an archive, but it does not seem to work.

I know `7-Zip` is installed correctly, since when I pass `--help` as a parameter to 7z, it works fine, the output is shown in PowerShell, but merging with this command line :

> CMD ["7z", "e -y -o"c:\" "c:\foo-foo.7z.001""]

tells me that `7z` is not an internal command or batch file etc.etc.

I suppose it's something to do with the argument list formatting, but several attempted modifications haven't worked so far.

Comment: the format is wrong, should be: CMD ["7z", "e", "-y", "-o", "c:\", "c:\foo-foo.7z.001"]. I don't know if this will fix your problem because I would need to see the DOckerfile first. Also just to be sure, you checked that 7z is installed INSIDE the container, right?

Comment: Hello. Yes I checked it. 7z.exe does get installed inside the container. Running `--help` or `i` with 7z always gets results, which implies 7z must be there, so I surmised the issue must have been formatting. I resolved it by using `ENTRYPOINT` with 7z and passing parameters using `CMD`, though I could not see the difference, but maybe I missed something in the documentation about it. I had tried the above formatting, in your comment, putting each argument separately, but that hadn't worked either...I'll try it, maybe I missed something.